# Compund assignment overload (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, parameter-passing

I encountered a problem when passing the same object twice by-reference to a function, once as a constant and once as usual (mutable).

I'd like to know what is the best way to fix such code.
(a Convenient example is, overloading compound-assignment operators).

```
class MyClass
{
    int a, b;
public:
    MyClass(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    MyClass& operator+=(const MyClass& ob)
    {
        this->a += ob.b;
        this->b += ob.a;    
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Of course, this code does not make a lot of sense, but it highlights the problem: 
When writing the following code:

```
MyClass ob(1, 2);
ob += ob;
```

I'd expect ob.b to have the value of 3, but it will have the value of 5.

I wonder how to implement such code correctly in general. 
Should I just be careful with the implementation, e.g maintaining temporary variables, or is there any better **general** solution for such problems? (E.g pass by value)

Comment: Assuming the class has a working/sane copy constructor, pass by value would fix the problem, since the function receives a copy of the right hand operand.     However, more generally, if you have a class for which addition works like this, it might be rather hard for users of your class to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a copied value (pass argument by value):

```
MyClass& operator+=(const MyClass ob)
```

Or a bit more optimized solution: compare objects addresses and use a temp value if objects are the same object:

```
MyClass& operator+=(const MyClass& ob)
{
    if (this == std::addressof(ob))
        return operator+=(MyClass(ob));
    this->a += ob.b;
    this->b += ob.a;    
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially emulating pass by value.   It also relies on the class not having an overloaded `operator&()`.

Comment: @Peter Ok, it is clear what you mind. I updated my answer to using `std::addressof`.